Upload large files on AWS ElasticBeanStalk
I have an environment on Elasticbeastalk and an s3 bucket to store files uploaded by clients through my web app.
When uploading a file 25M for example i get 413 Request Entity Too Large - nginx .
I have tried several solutions found online including modifying the nginx config file but still getting this error. I also change the instance type to t2.xlarge assuming it handles big uploads. im really stuck. what im doing wrong?
